# BASH - replace with variable contain double quotes inside

Tags: bash, awk, replace

I have an text file, with line inside...

line: <version="AAA" email="...ANY..." file="BBB">

new desired line in text file to be: <version="AAA" email="NEW_TEXT" file="BBB">

I want to replace the ...ANY... expression with variable (replace entire line)

I have this script text-file script in #!/bin/bash, but I have problem when expanding double quotes in variables.

> ```
> LINE_NUMBER="$(grep -nr 'email' *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
>
> VAR1="$(grep 'email' *.txt | cut -d '"' -f1-3)"
>
> VAR2="$(grep 'email' *.txt | cut -d '"' -f5-)"
>
> VAR3='NEW_TEXT'
>
> NEW_LINE=$VAR1'"'$VAR3'"'$VAR2
> new desired line in text file to be... <version="AAA" email="NEW_TEXT" file="BBB">
>
> awk -i inplace 'NR=='"$LINE_NUMBER"'{sub(".*",'"'$NEW_LINE'"')},1' *.txt
>
> but I get this new line:
> <version="" email="NEW_TEXT" file="">
> ```

what do I do wrong?

How can I prevent expand duouble quotes inside variable?
please better write me an working example, I had tried other topics, forums, posts....but I have no luck.

Comment: To edit xml files use xml aware programs. Like xmllint, xmlstarlet. `How can I prevent expand duouble quotes inside variable?` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: You should use sed.

Answer (score 0):

You cas use sed :

```
VAR3='NEW_TEXT'
sed -i "s/email=\"[^\"]*\"/email=\"$VAR3\"/" myfile.xml
```

Comment: THANKS!
it is working
how can I explain this portion of SED?....     email=\"[^\"]*\"

Comment: Replace `NEW_TEXT` with `NEW&TEXT` then try that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting:

```
  var3="text space % special < chars"
```

Note `var3` may not contain `&` which is special replacement meaning in `sed`

```
  sed -E 's|email="[^"]*"|email="'"${var3}"'"|' input.1.txt
```

#### Explanation

`[^"]*` : Match longest string not having `"` till next `"`.